# Economics behind reverse auctions with occasional non-profiting suppliers

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, general-equilibrium, auctions, market-failure

I was curious about the theory behind a reverse auction system where some suppliers act in a non-profit manner, namely, that their consideration of extra-auctions benefits of providing their service results in a free offer to the buyer.

Can such a system exist where there are some suppliers willing to provide free services and others suppliers that are not willing to provide free services?

Is an equilibrium possible if, say, 30% of the potential suppliers acted in such a voluntary manner or would this result in a market failure?

Any guiding thoughts or material would be very welcomed.

Edit: Most of the literature I've read came from the internal references within this review: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1366554503000711 (paywalled)

I also read about the auction rulesets defined in this work:
[https://web.stanford.edu/~milgrom/publishedarticles/Putting%20Auction%20Theory%20to%20Work.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emilgrom/publishedarticles/Putting%20Auction%20Theory%20to%20Work.pdf)

Neither of the above references, to my knowledge, accounted for the consequences of non-profit reverse auction bids.

Comment: Thanks @1muflon1 for the feedback and warm welcome. I'll try and put some of the material I've been looking through as reference.